# How to keep private keys in secured memory

Tags: c++, security, cryptography, openssl

I have a private key that I decrypt using a password from the user, but I need to use this private key quite often, and I don't want to keep it decrypted in the memory.

One option I thought of is encrypting the private key with a randomly generated one time password, and every time I use it, to replace the password, but still the one time password is kept in the memory.

Another option I thought about is using OpenSSL memory BIO. From what I understood it keeps the data inside it secured (I have no idea how it does that, but that's what I've heard).

What do you think is better? Are there any better options?
Thanks! :-)

p.s.
I'm using native C++ and OpenSSL.

Comment: Unless you have dedicated secure hardware, there's no way around keeping the key in memory one way or another. You'll definitely want to look into various secure memory APIs that give you access to non-pageable memory and guaranteed overwriting. Adding another layer of encryption to the key is possible, but will itself be amenable to attack... it really depends on your threat model.

Comment: Why do need the password multiple times? Is it to reauthenticate? Do actually need to authenticate?

Comment: @Kerrek: Do you know if OpenSSL's BIO is such secured memory API?

Comment: @Preet: I need to decrypt data in realtime using that private key, so I need to keep the private key in the memory.

Comment: What are the possible attacks you want to be resistant to?

Comment: I want to make sure that if someone creates a full dump of my process memory, the attacker won't be able to find the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition you are looking for means of [Security though obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  In this case the user has more control over the device than you do.  The secret must exist in plain text at some point,  and the attacker (the user),  can attach a debugger and view this value.   There will never be a solution to this problem,  it is not something that can be made secure.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't look for some security through obscurity, but I couldn't get anything better, so that's why I asked here :-).
Your answer reinforced my sad suspicion, that there is no software-only solution to the problem...

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably over-engineering the security part of the application.  The truth is that your application can be swapped out of memory at any point in time, which would mean the key could be written to disk before you're even able to remove the unencrypted version out of memory.

As someone suggested, you usually have some other memory-capable device that stores the key while you're using it.  Since it is an external device and not mapped into process memory, a swap or a dump won't get the key.  There are cheap and expensive variants.  One that I've explored using is an nCipher HSM (Hardware Security Module) that performs all operations on-board.  Your key is unlocked in the HSM's memory, but all crypto operations happen on the device.  They even have the ability for you to put compiled code in the HSM to run in a secure environment.  These are, however, quite expensive.